# Avoid additional fields in json apart from the fields defined in the swagger to fail the validation in WSO2 APIM 3.1.0

Tags: json, wso2, swagger, swagger-2.0, wso2-esb

We are trying to validate a json in APIM 3.1.0 by defining the validation conditions in swagger definition and by enabling the schema validation under runtime configurations. PFA the Swagger definition.

When additional fields are passed in the request json apart from the fields defined in the swagger, the validation must fail or gateway should ignore those additional fields and shouldn't be passing it to the backend. But this is not happening currently, Could you please suggest us if we are missing anything here.

****Sample Request JSON****

Note : In this JSON, "test" field is an additional parameter sent in the request.

{​​​​​​​
"applicationId": "Test123_3211",
"name": "Bala krishna",
"dateOfBirth": "1981-04-11",
"gender": "FEMALE",
"phonenumber": "9039283630",
"altphonenumber": "9979979971",
"panCard": "AAAAV1234N",
"nomineeName": "Ramji Ambedkar",
"nomineeDOB": "1976-04-14",
"source": "ONLINE",
"process": "Canara HSBC",
"callDate": "2018-08-24",
"callTime": "17:00",
"merType": "VIDEOMER",
"instantCall": true,
"test": "abcd"
}​​​​​​​

**Below is the swagger API :**

swagger: "2.0"
info:
version: v1.0.0
title: MedicalBookAppointmentAPI
description: "This API is for booking medical appointments. \n\nSupported operations :\n\n\t1. Docs APP "
schemes:

- https
- http
  produces:
- application/json
  paths:
  /docs-app:
  post:
  summary: This API will be used to add cases and to schedule appointments.
  description: This API will be used to add cases and to schedule appointments.
  parameters:
  - in: body
  name: Payload
  description: Request Body
  required: true
  schema:
  $ref: "#/definitions/docs-app-request"
  responses:
  "200":
  description: OK
  schema:
  $ref: "#/definitions/docs-app-response"
  "400":
  schema:
  $ref: "#/definitions/book-appointment-api-error"
  description: Bad Request. Invalid request or validation error.
  "415":
  schema:
  $ref: "#/definitions/book-appointment-api-error"
  description: " Unsupported Media Type. The entity of the request was in a not supported format."
  "500":
  schema:
  $ref: "#/definitions/book-appointment-api-error"
  description: Internal Server Error
  produces:
  - application/json
  consumes:
  - application/json
  x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
  x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
  definitions:
  docs-app-request:
  type: "object"
  required:
  - "applicationId"
  - "process"
  properties:
  applicationId:
  type: "string"
  name:
  type: "string"
  dateOfBirth:
  type: "string"
  pattern: "^\d{​​​​​​​4}​​​​​​​-\d{​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​-\d{​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​$"
  gender:
  type: "string"
  phonenumber:
  type: "number"
  altphonenumber:
  type: "number"
  panCard:
  type: "string"
  nomineeName:
  type: "string"
  nomineeDOB:
  type: "string"
  pattern: "^\d{​​​​​​​4}​​​​​​​-\d{​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​-\d{​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​$"
  source:
  type: "string"
  process:
  type: "string"
  planDetails:
  type: "string"
  priorityStatus:
  type: "string"
  callDate:
  type: "string"
  pattern: "^\d{​​​​​​​4}​​​​​​​-\d{​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​-\d{​​​​​​​2}​​​​​​​$"
  callTime:
  type: "string"
  metaInfo:
  type: "string"
  instantCall:
  type: "boolean"
  merType:
  type: "string"
  enum:
  - "TELEMER"
  - "VIDEOMER"
  - "OTHERS"
  docs-app-response:
  type: object
  properties:
  data:
  type: object
  properties:
  approved:
  type: boolean
  isInternational:
  type: boolean
  id:
  format: int64
  type: integer
  applicationId:
  type: string
  name:
  type: string
  dateOfBirth:
  type: string
  gender:
  type: string
  phonenumber:
  type: string
  altphonenumber:
  type: string
  panCard:
  type: string
  nomineeName:
  type: string
  nomineeDOB:
  type: string
  merType:
  type: string
  vendor:
  type: string
  updatedAt:
  type: string
  createdAt:
  type: string
  success:
  type: integer

book-appointment-api-error:
title: Error object returned with HTTP status
type: object
properties:
fault:
type: object
properties:
code:
format: int64
type: integer
type:
type: string
message:
description: Error message.
type: string
description:
description: A detail description about the error message.
type: string
required:
- code
- message

Comment: what is the response you got after sending the request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either **additionalProperties** or **minProperties/maxProperties** in the swagger file and restrict the additional properties in the payload.

- If you know the property count to be limited then use **minProperties/maxProperties**
- If you don't know the property count to be limited then use **additionalProperties**

For more details please refer https://m-saranki.medium.com/unboxing-json-schema-validator-320-2dd944dae6c0